# Using a custom gateway with Google Cloud Run on GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, istio, google-cloud-run

I have a GKE cluster on which I'm testing Google Cloud Run, which also hosts services that are not managed by Cloud Run. To access these, I've set up a simple Gateway and Virtual Service as described [here](https://programmaticponderings.com/2019/01/03/securing-your-istio-gateway-with-https/). This Gateway has successfully worked in a GKE cluster in which the Istio add-on was enabled and Cloud Run was not enabled.

It appears that in a cluster with Cloud Run enabled, my custom gateway is ignored, and that all traffic goes through a default gateway called istio-autogenerated-k8s-ingress. I suspect it might be because the default is defined for `Hosts: *`.

**How can I ensure my gateway for services not managed by Cloud Run takes precedence for the hosts for which it is responsible?** Is it safe to edit the autogenerated gateway? Will modifying it break Cloud Run? Will Cloud Run overwrite or modify this file in its normal operation?

Comment: I think you meant "I'm testing Google Cloud Run **on GKE**, which also hosts..."?

Comment: Have you added `VirtualService` for the `Gateway`?

Comment: Yes, I have, @Crou.

Answer (score 1):

istio-autogenerated-k8s-ingress is provided by Istio addon. CloudRun does not use it. So it is safe to delete it. It won't break CloudRun.

CloudRun on GKE use the Gateway knative-ingress-gateway under namespace knative-serving by default. I am curious about your use case. Do you also want to use your own Gateway to serve the traffic to CloudRun related services? If you want that, you can and add an entry "gateway.{your-own-gateway}: "istio-ingressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local" into the config-istio ConfigMap (https://github.com/knative/serving/blob/master/config/config-istio.yaml).

Comment: No, I'm trying to use my own gateway to serve traffic for specific hosts from services that are in the cluster, but which are not managed by CloudRun on GKE.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it safe to edit the autogenerated gateway?

Yes, but if you used the Cloud Run addon for your GKE cluster then it will be rewritten after a bit to then one from the addon.

> Will modifying it break Cloud Run?

If you write it incorrectly or make a mistake Cloud Run might not work.

> Will Cloud Run overwrite or modify this file in its normal operation?

As explained above, if you used addon to deploy Cloud Run to your cluster then the config might be modified automatically after some time because everything is pre-configured.

Have you used this guide [Setting up Cloud Run on GKE](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/gke/setup)? If so please read [serving/pkg/reconciler/route/README.md](https://github.com/knative/serving/blob/ee57bc225eeb96093d006ed401dbb9d92a1a7446/pkg/reconciler/route/README.md) as it might be helfull.

Comment: yes, i did follow that guide, thanks. the clarifications here are helpful. one thing i'm still unclear on though: i know knative adds its own ingress gateway to avoid conflicting with istio-ingressgateway. what i'm trying to understand is if both gateways are used, or if the knative one takes precedence. From the routes README: "In the future we should probably provide a way for the users to select what the Gateway they use -- and how Knative would expect such Gateway to look like." makes me think only the knative one will be used.